# ActiveX Data Objects (ADO) in wcf not working after deployment

Tags: silverlight, wcf, iis, adodb, activexobject

i am using  ActiveX Data Objects (ADO) in my silverlight application to show the create database connectoin wizard .. data link properties dialog box .. this is create and showed in the background WCF service.

this works perfectly fine when i run it from visual studio 2010. but when i deploy it in my local IIS, it does not show up.

i have tried cathing the exception, but there is none.

The flow just stops here ( marked in bold and italics). I also have the client ploicy and crossdomain file in wwwroot

Log("before adodb");
                MSDASC.DataLinks dataLinks = new MSDASC.DataLinks();

```
            Log("after adodb");
            if (dataLinks == null)
                Log("Data link is null");
            else
                Log("data link isi not null");
            //note that a reference to: 
            //  c:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\adodb.dll
            //is also required to read the ADODB._Connection result
            ADODB._Connection connection;
            Log("Promting for new connection");
            ***connection = (ADODB._Connection)dataLinks.PromptNew();***
            Log("after new connection");
```

any help is appreciated . thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use Active X components, you have to run the application out-of-browser. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes. and it worked. any possibility where i can access COM resource from browser?

Comment: Active X is accessible if the user allows the access within the security settings of the browser. But it is a huge security leak that's why most users deny the access (at least for Internet sites). If somebody installs a Silverlight application out of browser he trusts the application and takes the risk.